# Tibco Websphere MQ Adapter

Tags: tibco

I want to know all about the MQ adapter starting from what products are necessary to be installed on our machine for configuring and running the adapter locally,o how we create and interact with queue managers,configuration.

Comment: Read the FAQ: "Your questions should be reasonably scoped. If you can imagine an entire book that answers your question, you’re asking too much. ". Besides that if you want others to do your work for you hire them.

Comment: Is this how you increase your popularity.I am learning on my own and have been trying to put things together.This is no way to treat a question and let me tell u I am using it for the first time.

Comment: Which is all fine and by all means go for it. I'm just pointing you to the FAQ that explains what type of questions are suited for this site and which ones are not. At this point in time your question is way too generic and fails to show any effort from your side. Therefor it's unlikely to get any answer and I'm actually surprised it hasn't been closed yet. For more on how to ask questions see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask

Comment: I just felt you were rude.I was able to put all the information related to MQ Adapters in place.But it took me a lot of time.We can always reply in a sensible and polite manner. Thanks

Comment: @ aarti... voted up the down vote. @eddy.. please let her ask what she wants to know about the adapters and its configuration is not that easy, many times the content of book/pdf dont work so its obvious that we guyz can use stackoverflow however i would have appriciated if aarti had mentioned where does she has looked for the answer and she could have been more specific.

Comment: @aarti please dont use word rude for eddy... he is just helping to make stackoverflow better.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look to http://power.tibco.com/ and search for KB 107430

Here are the explanations on how to get BW and MQ working together :

http://power.tibco.com/app/kb/article.jsp?aid=107430

1) Java components of WS MQ must be installed (there should be a jms.jar file in the WS MQ directory) (note that this is part of default installation with WS MQ 5.3 and 6.0) 
2) JNDI set-up 
- Create the following directory: C:\tibco\JNDI-Directory - cd C:\IBM\MQ\Java\bin (where C:\IBM\MQ is the home directory for your WS MQ installation) 
- Edit JMSAdmin.config so that: - INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY=com.sun.jndi.fscontext.RefFSContextFactory - PROVIDER_URL=file:/C:/TIBCO/JNDI-Directory 
3) Edit JNDI configuration jmsadmin.bat with the following : 
DEFINE QCF(QueueConnectionFactory)+ QMANAGER(MY_QMGR) (where MY_QMGR is the name of your queue manager) 
DEFINE Q(WMQ.MY_QUEUE)+ (where MY_QUEUE is the name of your queue) 
QMANAGER(MY_QMGR)+ 
QUEUE(MY_QUEUE)+ 
TARGCLIENT(MQ)

In theory this should be repeated for all the queues you want to access from BW but in practice only one queue is enough. - Check with 'DISPLAY CTX'

- Exit with 'END' Note that "QueueConnectionFactory" name must match Queue Connection Factory defined in the "JMS Connection" Advanced Panel.

4) BW configuration - Edit tibco\bw\5.3\bin\bwengine.tra so that tibco.env.CUSTOM_EXT_APPEND_CP includes C:/IBM/MQ/Java/lib - Edit tibco\designer\5.3\bin\designer.tra so that tibco.env.CUSTOM_CP_EXT includes C:/IBM/MQ/Java/lib